# Cannot create images in a canvas with for loop

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have the following code which is suppose to do the following:

1. Create 2 Canvas elements on the html page dynamically (this works fine)
2. For each Canvas element, examine the allSteps variable which is a representation of what images should appear in what position of the canvas element. In this hard coded example, it should display two black boxes at the bottom of the first canvas and two brown boxes at the bottom of the 2nd canvas. (this doesn't work properly). All images are 50x50.

For some reason, it is only loading one image at the end of the 2nd canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

        var boxImages = ['img/white.jpg', 'img/blue.jpg', 'img/black.jpg', 'img/brown.jpg', 'img/green.jpg', 'img/red.jpg'];
        var IMAGE_WIDTH=50;
        var MAX_COLS = 7;
        var MAX_ROWS = 8;
        var numberOfSteps = 2;
        var allSteps = [];
        allSteps[0] = '0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2';
        allSteps[1] = '0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3';

        $('#result_div').html('<p>All Steps : ' + allSteps + '</p>');

        for (count=0; count < numberOfSteps; count++)
        {
            $('#result_div').append('<h3>Step : ' + count + '</h3>');
            $('#result_div').append('<p><canvas id="resultCanvas' + count + '" width="350" height="400" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;" ></p>');
            resultCanvas=document.getElementById('resultCanvas'+count);
            resultCtx = resultCanvas.getContext("2d");  

            currentSolution = allSteps[count].split(" ");
            for (r=0; r < MAX_ROWS; r++)    
            {
                for (c=0; c < MAX_COLS; c++)
                {
                    imgNumber=currentSolution[((r)*MAX_COLS)+c];
                    if (imgNumber != 0)
                    {                   

                        boxX = (c*IMAGE_WIDTH);
                        boxY = (r*IMAGE_WIDTH);
                        cimg=new Image();
                        cimg.onload = function(){resultCtx.drawImage(cimg,boxX,boxY);};
                        cimg.src=boxImages[imgNumber];  
                    }                           
                }
            }
        }
   });
   </script>
<body>

<div id="result_div"></div>


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this yet, but I guess you overwrite your `cimg.src` and `cimg.onload` faster than the images are actually loaded. Have you tried using an array of images instead?

```
    var cimgs = [];

    var IMAGE_WIDTH=50;
    /*
        ...
    */

            if (imgNumber != 0)
            {                   

                boxX = (c*IMAGE_WIDTH);
                boxY = (r*IMAGE_WIDTH);
                cimgs.push(new Image());
                cimgs[cimgs.length - 1].onload = (function(img,x,y){
                    return function(){resultCtx.drawImage(img,x,y);};
                })(cimgs[cimgs.lenght - 1],boxX,boxY);
                cimgs[cimgs.length - 1].src = boxImages[imgNumber];  
            }                           
        }
```

Comment: This would be my guess as well. When working with canvas and images, you should always make sure the onload event has fired for all the images before attempting to draw them as it may even cause errors if it isn't loaded yet.

Comment: I tested this, but it didn't work. After the change, no images were showing (as opposed to one before). May I ask why the array is being used here? Is it suppose to allow the image loading/rendering process to be synchronous with the loop? Are there other ways for ensuring the onload event has fired for an image before drawing the next one? Thank you guys for all your help so far and I'll be happy to read any references where I can find more info about this topic. :)

Comment: Found the solution here: http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/canvas/multiple-onload.html